# Почему Requests даёт содержимое ответа сервера в непонятной кодировке?

Tags: python, requests

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.livelib.ru/genre/Триллеры/top'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
title = soup.find('a', class_='brow-book-name with-cycle').get_text()
print(title)
print(res.encoding)
```

```
ÐŸÐ¾Ð±ÐµÐ³ Ð¸Ð· Ð¨Ð¾ÑƒÑˆÐµÐ½ÐºÐ°
ISO-8859-1
```

В заголовке кода HTML указана кодировка: `content="text/html; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: а в хидере контент-тайп что указанно?

Comment: @eri не очень понял. Вот строка в тэге <head>: <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

Comment: При этом вы в суп скормили только текст `res.text`, заголовок он поэтому не смог увидеть, он отрезался. Попробуйте скормить ему всё содержимое страницы целиком `res.content`.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо, работает.

Comment: Мой вопрос нужно отметить решённым?

Comment: Наверняка это дубликат, я много раз на подобные вопросы отвечал. Мне просто лень искать подходящие вопросы.